# Is a "program" which is not a server application affected by the log4shell vulnerability?

Tags: log4j

what I do not understand from the log4shell problems... Lets say we have a simple program which uses the log4j module.
Is this program which doesn't serve anything like a webserver or any application which serves an application to the internet/network vulnerable in any way?

Regards
Ubbu

Answer (score 0):

ANY application that uses log4j2 can be vulnerable, also desktop applications, which don't serve anything to the internet as long as the executing system has a connection to the internet enabled.

Reason:
The application is vulnerable, when it logs a certain String. This could be e.g. the content of a file you open with a Java desktop application. If you are tricked to open a prepared file with a known vulnerable desktop application, just opening the file will log the String. This will load arbitrary code from the internet (almost any device is constantly connected to the internet), and executes that code on your machine.

So yes, any java application might be affected. Not limited to server applications serving web content.

IF your program has only static log messages, it is not exploitable. But almost any program logs any kind of "user" input. It's just that you not always know that you are providing a program input right now.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously not. ;)

But if you have a connection to the internet later on then it would be :)

Comment: In the sense of connecting to the internet or serving an application to the internet? :D

Comment: @Ubbu In sense of serving and connecting if you want to avoid don't serve/connect something :D